# Best way to Auto move files and folders from Debain to Windows FTP

Tags: windows, debian, ftp

I have a folder called "Leeching Done" on my debian server. Now is there a way this folder could be scanned every 10 minutes or so and if new files/folders are there move them via FTP.

Comment: see if you have rsync on the debian server. If so, that would be the easiest way to sync files from server to your other computer.

Comment: rsync don't work with FTP I belive. http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Comment: Yes I know. I was suggesting you use rsync instead of FTP. If you want to use FTP, you can use a FTP syncing program liked Beyond Compare to retrieve files that are missing via FTP.